# Set number of slides shown for mobile?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm using the [Slick Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) module in my D7 layout and it's awesome. My carousel view is currently set to Grid, and to display 9 slides at a time. That said, how can I set the view to display a different number of slides (at different sizes) when the site is being viewed from a mobile device? For example, if the browser is open on a phone and only 414px wide, I want to display 1 slide in the carousel instead of 9 slides with their current image style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the **Slick UI**, then press on configure.

[image]

Click on the List tab, and edit the default.

[image]

You need to add some breakpoints, make sure you select the correct skin.

[image]

Comment: Tried this just now - added the breakpoints 376px & 414px (widths of iPhone 6 and 6plus), but 9 slides still display on mobile?

Comment: @Brittany did you select the correct skin? (top right of last pic, highlighted in green). Did you also clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, correct skin selected and cache cleared.

Comment: @Brittany I've never used this module before, I can't even the Slick Carousel to work. Perhaps you should give [Owl Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel) a try. I've used this before. (same procedure, enable the UI and configure).

Comment: @Brittany is your slick content coming from an image field in different nodes? or an image field with unlimited values form a single node?

Comment: My content is coming from a custom view containing a list of fields. E.g. title field, body field, and image field .

Comment: @Brittany and the image field allows only 1 image? right?

Comment: This is correct!